# 'Def addition()' not working

Tags: python, import, function

```
import random

def multiply():
    num1 = random.randint(1,12)
    num2 = random.randint(1,12)
    ans = int(input("What is the answer to " + str(num1) + " x " + str(num2) + " ? "))
    correct = (ans == num1 * num2)
    if correct:
        print("You are correct! ")
    else:
        print("Wrong, please try again. ")
    return correct

def addition():
    num1 = random.randint(1,12)
    num2 = random.randint(1,12)
    ans = int(input("What is the answer to " + str(num1) + " + " + str(num2) + " ? "))
    correct = (ans == num1 + num2)
    if correct:
        print("You are correct! ")
    else:
        print("Wrong, please try again. ")
    return correct

name = input("What is your name? ")
maths = input("What mathematics would you like to learn, " + name + "? ")
if maths == "Multiplication" or "m" or "x":
    correct = multiply() 
elif maths == "Addition" or "a" or "x":
    correct == addition()
```

I am having trouble getting the second 'def addition' to work. The first 'def multiply' works and runs correctly, however the 'def multiply' still won't work.

Any thoughts on how I can make this work?

Comment: You have `correct == addition()`

Comment: hi what is ` or "m" or "x":` ? The first `if condition` is always true `if maths == "Multiplication" or "m" or "x":`  So your code will call ` multiply()` function every time.

Comment: Also you can't `or` together strings. Have a list and check whether a value is in it: `if maths in ["Addition",  "a", "x"]:`

Comment: I guess also `"x"` should be `"+"`.

Comment: `"Multiplication" or "m" or "x"` will always return true

Comment: You also want to read [How do I test one variable against multiple values?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15112125); you are making the same mistake in your own boolean tests.

Answer (score 2):

change == to = as it is assignment

```
 correct = addition()
```